# Valid Jar Clasifiers

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am attempting to build and publish a test source jar to accompany a test jar. I have seen "test" and "src" used as classifiers for jars, but I have not see anything for a test src jar.

Additionally I have not been able to find any documention on valid jar classifier. I did find some [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier) for maven that suggests this is just a string, however I assume there must be some standards because most IDEs automatically pulls down source jars...

Is there a list of valid jar classifiers? What are the standard/acceptable jar classifier? What should I use for a test source jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "valid" classifiers, simply because you can choose anything as a classifier (at least if you use no special characters). There are indeed some conventions (like sources or javadoc), however, there is no convention for a test source JAR (in the way, that it could be detected by an IDE or something else), so choose whatever you want (i'd choose `test-sources`).